# How can I combine (or make operations) between attributes of different classes (without specifying instances yet)?

Tags: python, class, instances

First of all, I am a total newbie. Thanks for your patience.

I am designing a piece of software to calculate insulation materials and amounts on different houses.

I have a `class House()`, which holds attributes like roof_area and wall_area.

I have a `class Insulator()`, which holds attributes like thickness and area (the area the packaged material covers)

Now I want to know how many packages of the insulator I should buy in order to cover the whole roof area.

So, the operation would be:

```
House.roof_area / Insulator.area = insulator_packages_needed_for_roof
```

The thing is I can't do that operation:

```
AttributeError: type object 'House' has no attribute 'roof_area'.
```

Of course I could do it a an instance scope, but I don't want to specify an instance yet, as this operation should be done for any instance of the Class that gets build in the future. Should I use inheritance? My feeling is that, given that Insulator and House are totally different things, they shouldn't be mixed by inheritance, but I am just a beginner.

Comment: Can you show the code for the House class? The error indicates that roof_area is not static, and instead being set inside a method or the __init__

Comment: You could just do it with a method inside the house class, something like `def area(x): return self.roof_area/x.area`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to try to compute the number of insulation packages you need to cover the roof of a house, without using any instances  of your `House` or `Insulator` classes. It only makes sense if you have one instance of each.

You can, however, write the code to do the calculation before you've created the instances. Just put it in a function that takes the instances as arguments:

```
def roof_insulation_packages(house, insulator):  # args are instances of House and Insulator
    return house.roof_area / insulator.area  # do the calculation and return it
```

It might make more sense for the function to be a method of one of the classes. I'd even suggest that `Insulator` instances might be a good candidates to be instance attributes of the `House`. That would look something like this:

```
class House():
    def __init__(self, roof_area, roof_insulator, wall_area, wall_insulator):
        self.roof_area = roof_area
        self.roof_insulator = roof_insulator
        self.wall_area = wall_area
        self.wall_insulator = wall_insulator

    def calculate_roof_insulation_packages(self):
        return self.roof_area / self.roof_insulator.area

    def calculate_wall_insulation_packages(self, insulator):
        return self.wall_area / self.wall_insulator.area
```

You'd create the house instance with something like this (I'm making up the arguments to the `Insulator` class, so don't pay too much attention to that part):

```
good_roof_insulation = Insulator(4, 5) # nonsense args
cheap_wall_insulation = Insulator(5, 12)

my_house = House(100, good_roof_insulation, 87, cheap_wall_insulation)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Blckknight. Your first solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use attributes without creating an instance you should use class attributes.

```
class House(object):
    roof_area = 10 # Or whatever you see fit.
    roof_surface = 20

class Insulator(object):
    thickness = 10 # Or whatever you see fit.
    surface = 20
```

This way you can access the attributes by typing 'House.roof_area' for example.

Although, I don't see why you cannot create an instance. It would prevent harcoding in class attributes and would in your case be much easier.

Also, your operation is not valid syntax, but maybe you just showed pseudo-code. Proper syntax would be:

```
insulator_packages_needed_for_roof = House.roof_area / Insulator.area
```